# How to fetch all table data but order should be based on multiple categories?

Tags: mysql, sorting

I'm working on a project having some products information and their properties. But I'm stuck in the filtration process. Lets say the table is as follows

**Table 1**

```
item_id | item_name | item_color | item_type | item_sole
```

**Items user has visited**

```
user_id | item_id | is_liked
```

**User's preferences** : As soon as user liked or disliked a item I'm maintaining another table where I'm storing the item's properties

```
user_id | items_property  //Items property is a serialised array where 
                          //I'm storing the value of item_color, item_type, item_sole
```

Now the next items will displayed based on the analytics I've done.

- I want to display all the items which are not yet liked or disliked
- The list order preference based on the **item_color, item_type** and **item_sole** user liking the most. **For e.g.** Lets say user has liked 4 items already out of which 3 has type sports and 2 of them has color white and rest 2 have black and brown color. Its means user likes sports shoes of white color. So my query for the next item should display sports shoes of white color on priority, if no white color presents, list can also display sports shoes with the other color he liked. If no sports shoes present, color should be the on priority. If no sports, no color, then the rest item can be displayed.
- I hope you understand that I've to analyse what type of data user liking and disliking and based on users liked I've to display the items orders.

Please suggest, I'm not much familiar with `MySql`

Comment: Can you elaborate your second requirement?

Comment: I've updated my 2nd point. let me know if you understood what I want to elaborate

Comment: show a table schema for tables relevant with `show create table myTable` for each. Show sample data, and expected results